# Mule Post XML Payload

Tags: mule

Hello Im quite new to MULE, I have a problem using the XML to Object Transformer, I have a HTTP node followed by "XML TO OBJECT" Transformer in the configuration I am specifying Driver Class as com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream and in the advanced tab I am specifying

```
<mulexml:alias name="Person" class="org.hello.Person"/>
```

This keeps on failing the deployment I cant understand why...  can anyone please help....

Person is the root tag of xml and org.hello.person is the java class which fits the xml...

the exception is

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream cannot be cast to com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamDriver
```

my intention is to first conver the xml to java object and then use EML on the object to take routing decisions...

Comment: What's an "HTTP node"? Do you mean an HTTP inbound endpoint? Also what Mule version are you using? And how do you POST the XML to Mule?

Comment: I am using Version 3.5.0 I posted the xml through SOAP UI to the URL Configured on HTTP Inbound endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to specify a driver class: remove it and things should work.

Comment: org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException: person (com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException). Message payload is of type: ContentLengthInputStream (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException). Message payload is of type: ContentLengthInputStream

Comment: i take that back there was a missing tag... thanks for answering my question